# RedDot: referencing an element in a template's container

Tags: content-management-system, reddot

I have a template with ~ 50 existing instances. I now need to add an
element to a container within those pages, so I've referenced the
content on a container within the template. However, the existing
pages have not picked that reference up - how do I 'apply' this
reference to existing instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a plugin that would "reference element in all instances" that would work. It should work for RedDot 6 and 7. I've uploaded the plugin here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2453/Plugin_linkref_allpages.zip.

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing connected the plugin should work. If there is something connected however, the reference will remove the connected page (page will become unlinked), and then replace it with the reference.

FYI, I believe that plugin actually works up to v10. Check out solutionexchange.info for more plugins as well.